# Creating Date Object by parsing select_date form helper only works sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the relevant part in the form:

```
<%= select_date(@end_date, {order: [:month, :day, :year], start_year: 2009, end_year: Time.now.year, prefix: "end_date"},{class: "form-control date-select"} ) %>
```

Here is what is passed through the params when the form is submitted:

```
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>”123”,
 "end_date"=>{"month"=>"8", "day"=>"25", "year"=>"2014"},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "controller"=>”some_controller”,
 "action"=>”some_action”}
```

And in the controller here is how I create the date object from the params:

```
Date.parse params["end_date"].values.join("-")
```

The odd thing is that it only works sometimes.  For example, when the user selects the date above (August 25th, 2015), It comes up with the following error:

```
invalid date
```

And it highlights the area where I am parsing the date:

```
Date.parse params["end_date"].values.join("-")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this expression:

```
params["end_date"].values.join("-")
```

Will give you string `'8-25-2014'`. When parsing date, ruby is trying to guess the format you are using, and in this case it uses `dd-mm-yyyy`. That means that what you think is 10th of November will be read by Ruby as 11th of October (which is even worse than an exception while getting 25th month).

Best solution - do not use parse. You already know the values, why give a parser opportunity to make a mistake?

```
Date.new *params[:end_date].values_at(:year, :month, :day).map(&:to_i)
```

Note: You will still need to wrap the code above in `begin rescue` as your users can (and will) pick dates like 31 of Feb.